# Exporting CSV of users with custom user taxonomies out of Wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users, taxonomy, export, csv

I'm trying to export a CSV or XML out of a WordPress site that has custom taxonomies added to the users. The site I'm working with adds custom taxonomies following the [format here.](https://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress)

Plenty of export plugins will export `users` and export `user taxonomies`, but they don't do both, in the same way if you export `posts` there is typically a column for taxonomies.

What I want is to export a table of `users` that has a "taxonomy" column and each user has the terms that apply to them in their row.

I've scoured the internet and it seems like there's not help here. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: SInce you did ask about a plugin, if it is acceptable (mods?) to add a link to a plugin that will work - I can post that as an answer if it's not against Stack Exchange terms. I used it recently for a simlar project.

Comment: WPAllImport is the plugin I am referring to - I can post info if needed. LMK

Comment: @WhisparDesign Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately that plugin does not export a table that includes user taxonomies with users. I've tried it multiple ways.

Comment: Wow - even with the Pro Version and the ACF add-on? I did not know that - good to know.